# Drawing rectangles on the right

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-studio

Below is the code for a rectangle to be drawn 0 pixels from the left, but how can I set a rectangle to be drawn at 0 pixels from the right hand side of the screen?

```
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <package.name.customview.Diagram
        android:id="@+id/diagram"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Diagram.java**

```
package com.apptacularapps.customview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Diagram extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Diagram(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(canvas.getWidth() - 5, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new class - DrawView.java

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.view.View;

    public class DrawView extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    //Code to Measure the Screen width in pixels

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;

            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 5, canvas.getHeight(), paint );

    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(width-canvas.getWidth(), 0, width, canvas.getHeight(), paint );
        }
}
```

In your Diagram.java, change your onDraw Method as below.

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        DrawView drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }
```

**Update - To resolve your error, try this**

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

instead of

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
```

**update 2 - To resolve context error.**

Add this line `Context context;` below this line `Paint paint = new Paint();`

Add this line `this.context = context;` below this line `super(context);`

update 3 - Use this code sample

Diagram.java

package com.casestudy.intentsandfilter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class Diagram extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        setContentView(drawView);

    }
}
```

DrawView.java

```
package com.casestudy.intentsandfilter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 80, 80, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 77, 77, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );

    }

}
```

Comment: Apologies Diagram.java shouldn't be there

Comment: I now get this error `Can't resolve method 'getWindowManager()'` check latest screenshot above.

Comment: Still left with an error, check my update screenshot

Comment: App still crashes. Remember my rectangle needs to be on right hand side of the screen.

Comment: @user3293579, you have no activity class. So your app is getting crashed. So extend your class by Activity and add this in a different class.